# CSS y HTML como centrar cuadros de formulario

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Hola buena tengo una duda no se como alinear los cuadros de textos(input) y los label que queden bien centrados, el caso es que también tengo un textarea, para hacer el típico formulario pero no me deja. Dejo mi código.

Este sería el formulario

```css
.formulario {
    
    display: block;
    padding: 10pxx;
}
```

```html
<div class="formulario">
    <form action="">
        <div>
            <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
            <input id="nombre" type="text">
        </div>
<div>
    <label for="asunto">Asunto</label>
    <input id="asunto" type="text">
</div>

<div>
    <label for="correo">Correo:</label>
    <input id="correo" type="email">
</div>

<div>
    <label for="nensaje">Mensaje</label>
    <textarea name="" id="mensaje" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Centrar vertical u horizontal o ambos?

Comment: [Edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/414014/edit) tu pregunta y especifica lo que quieres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es alinear los cuadros, ocurre que la etiqueta `label` es de tipo `inline`, es decir que su ancho será el mismo que ocupe el texto y los cuadros de los formularios se colocarán justo al lado.

Una solución sencilla sería colocar la etiqueta `label` a tipo `inline-block` y darle un ancho fijo (`width`):

```css
.formulario {
    
    display: block;
    padding: 10pxx;
}

label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="formulario">
    <form action="">
        <div>
            <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
            <input id="nombre" type="text">
        </div>
<div>
    <label for="asunto">Asunto</label>
    <input id="asunto" type="text">
</div>

<div>
    <label for="correo">Correo:</label>
    <input id="correo" type="email">
</div>

<div>
    <label for="nensaje">Mensaje</label>
    <textarea name="" id="mensaje" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Esto no funcionaria `10pxx`

Answer (score 1):

Imagino que con "centrar" te refieres a esto.

Te falta añadir el CSS a los demás elementos. Aquí te he hecho un arreglo básico:

```css
.formulario {
    
    display: block;
    padding: 10pxx;
    text-align:center;
    border:1px solid black;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.formulario div {
width:40%;
margin: 40px auto;
text-align:left;
}

#message-label {
display:inline-block;
width:100%;
margin-bottom:10px;
text-align:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="formulario">
    <form action="">
        <div>
            <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
            <input id="nombre" type="text">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="asunto">Asunto</label>
            <input id="asunto" type="text">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="correo">Correo:</label>
            <input id="correo" type="email">
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="mensaje" id="message-label">Mensaje</label>
            <textarea name="" id="mensaje" cols="30" rows="10"> </textarea>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```